# Transparent proxy for SSH connection with VS Code in use

Tags: ssh, proxy

As the title said, I'm looking for a method to use SSH via a http/socks5 proxy. The proxy service provider software is `ClashForWindows`.

### Some notations

- `C` is a Windows 11 Home device running VS Code, with remote-SSH extension installed and enabled.
- `S1`, `S2` are the remote servers, which is located in a lab under an intranet network. `S1` is a web server on Arduino. `S2` is a server with Windows 10 Server installed. Though the lab has its own public IPv4 address, it is blocked by the admin, which means I could not reach it by means of the public address.
- `P` is the proxy server.

### Current situation

On `C`, `ClashForWindows` is installed and the proxy is enabled on 127.0.0.1:7890. Both http and socks5 are available since I'm using them on Edge browser with SwitchyOmega add-on.

To give an example of current situation, let's say `S1` has an IP 10.0.0.7 and `S2` has an IP 10.0.0.8.

Currently, I could use the browser on `C` to visit the website deployed on `S1` through the proxy server. That is to say, `C <--> P <--> S1` is working properly.

However, I cannot use the VS Code on `C` to establish SSH connection with `S2`, even though I have set proxy in VS Code settings. I've also tried to enable system proxy in settings of `ClashForWindows`. Details of proxy settings in VS Code can be seen in the picture below.

[image: Proxy settings in VS Code]

### Problems to solve

1. How to achieve something like `C <--> P <--> S2` ?
2. Are there any barriers for SSH connections to use a http/socks5 proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

start vscode with below command
code --proxy-server="xxx.xx.xx.xx:port"

add command in desktop for vscode

/usr/share/applications/code.desktop

Exec=/usr/share/code/code --proxy-server="xx.x.x.xx:xxx" --unity-launch %F